# Changing status bar background color prior to Lollipop?

Tags: java, android, android-statusbar

In Lollipop we can set status bar color using method :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)

What should we use for Android versions prior to Lollipop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to say. You just **can't.**

Apps prior to Lollipop had no authority/permission to change status bar color.